# Flutter, cannot show application icon using flutter_launcher_icons

Tags: flutter, icons

Once a while, I have temporarily set icon A as the app icon and is was successfully set in Android device.  Now I would like to change to icon B, I added the ico file to the project, modified pubspec.yaml (letter cases are correct), update dependencies (actually I restarted Android Studio) and build.  The app icon still remains the old icon A.  Moreover, I build the app directly to my iPhone through XCode, the app icon is still the flutter icon.

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.11.0"

flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "images/AST.ico"
```

Comment: show me the log after entering this cmd 
$ flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main

Comment: flutter clean. flutter pub get. If that does not work. If you are using android studio Invalidate Caches and restart Android Studio. Sometimes during build android studio ignore file changes.

Comment: Yes, by running fultter pub run flutter_launcher+icons:main, it says icon generated successfully and android app changes to new icon.  But it doesn't seem to work on iOS devices.